# Removing Storyboard to use XIB files

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xib

Im new to iOS development completely and could use some help.

For an app I have been asked to write, I have been asked to code using just XIB files, not a storyboard. This is to help get a better understanding and follow coding conventions of another project I am getting involved in.

So, I have followed various advice on this site/youtube/google and keep running into the same problem.

Here are the steps I take.

- Delete Storyboard and default view controller files
- Delete relationship in the info.plist
- Created a new class, creating the XIB file in the process
- Set the main interface to the new XIB file (In general settings)
- Added viewController property to AppDeligate.h
- Added the below code to AppDeligate.m

  ```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  // Override point for customization after application launch.
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc]      initWithNibName:@"PhotoViewController_ipad" bundle:nil];
  self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;}
  ```

The problem I keep getting is when run in the simulator, It crashes on start and I recive the error fed back from the one line in the 'main' file. The error is 'Thread 1 SIGART'.

After researching, I see this could be to do with the relationship between the XIB file and the class files. as this has been created for me, it is correct, although, I have made sure myself that it is related to the class. and the File owner of the XIB is related to the view

Sorry about the long description. Long story short. I just want to start, and create my app throughout without a storyboard and just use XIB files

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using an exception breakpoint to see what is causing the crash?

Comment: Seems to come from the only line of code in main?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had to do this a couple of times. You'll want to make sure you add your AppDelegate to your MainWindow.xib file you are using to replace the storyboard. Make sure you get all of your delegates and windows connected properly so you have an appropriate outlet on startup.

MainWindow.xib

- AppDelegate added (connected to Window and Delegate)
- Window added (and connected to the Window in your AppDel)
- File Owner (connected to delegate)

Info.plist

- Main nib file base name (set to your MainWindow.xib)

I basically took an older project and made sure things were connected properly and my MainWindow looked correct. If you haven't added a UIWindow to your AppDelegate, you'll need to do that too.

[image]

If you have the info on the crash, we can likely help you further.

Comment: This is great help, Sorry if this sounds silly, but how do I go about adding the AppDeligate to the XIB file?

Comment: You can drag and drop on from the component list. Similar to adding a UILabel, just further down the list. It should automatically add it correctly, you'll just need to hook up the outlets in IB.

Comment: I know this is some time ago, but I am following these steps and have added the App Delegate to the document outline, but how do I add the window and delegate outlets?